# Home No such File or directory?

Tags: filesystem, home-directory

I have a switched graphics laptop. Often when I  up update Ubuntu (I am on on 3.00.00.14) it overwrites the Radeon driver and when I dont have that I cant boot. Until someone tells me a better way I usually go into the downloads directory where I keep a copy of the driver and re-install.
This time after I login from recovery. when I type cd/home/antony/Downloads it tells me -bash: cd/home/antony/Downloads: No such file or directory.....
Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?
thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cd/home/antony/Downloads` is not a file or directory. Insert a space.

```
cd /home/antony/Downloads
```

Comment: duhhhhh yeah sorry to nervous trying to get laptop up..thanks

Comment: P.s. If someonone can tell me how to avoid that each time I update the ATI driver gets overwritten I would be gratefull..

Comment: @Antony Please ask that as a new question.